# I switched to using polyglossia for some hebrew text and all of em dashed in my text reverted to three dashes

Tags: luatex, punctuation, polyglossia

Switching from babel to plyglossia in my text seems to be associaed with em dashes (typed as three dashes in a row) now being printed as three dashes.

I assume that the change to polyglossia is conincidental --- what could be causing this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{EB Garamond}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}[Script=Hebrew]{Hadasim CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}


\title{Using Hebrew Fonts on Overleaf with polyglossia \\\texthebrew{דוגמא לגופני ברירת מחדל}}
\author{Foo}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

I don't know why it is doing this --- but  I don't like it.

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should use \setmainfont{EB Garamond} instead of defining \englishfont. But why do you switch from babel to polyglossia??

Answer (score 5):

`\newfontfamily` doesn't load the `\defaultfontfeatures`.

Note: I changed the Hebrew font to one I have.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{EB Garamond}[Ligatures=TeX]

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Raanana}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}{Raanana}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}{Raanana}[Script=Hebrew]


\title{Using Hebrew Fonts on Overleaf with polyglossia \\\texthebrew{דוגמא לגופני ברירת מחדל}}
\author{Foo}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

I don't know why it is doing this --- but  I don't like it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

But it's much better to use `\setmainfont`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Raanana}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}{Raanana}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}{Raanana}[Script=Hebrew]


\title{Using Hebrew Fonts on Overleaf with polyglossia \\\texthebrew{דוגמא לגופני ברירת מחדל}}
\author{Foo}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

I don't know why it is doing this --- but  I don't like it.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks --- \setmainfont worked

Comment: Is the issue that \newfontfamily does not implicitly set ligatures?

Comment: @MichaelWagner Yes: `\setmainfont` respects the standard `\defaultfontfeatures` (which includes `Ligatures=TeX`), but `\newfontfamily` doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned `babel`, in case you decide to stick to it, here is how to do it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english, bidi=default]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{EB Garamond}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Hadasim CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{Miriam CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}{Miriam Mono CLM}

\title{Using Hebrew Fonts on Overleaf with Babel\\%
  \foreignlanguage{hebrew}{דוגמא לגופני ברירת מחדל}}
\author{Foo}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

I don't know why it is doing this --- but  I don't like it.

\end{document}
```

[image]